# Loop not printing more than once

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have tried a few types of loops, While, Do and For.

```
For i = 1 To 3

Cells(i, 20) = i

Next
```

It print once "1" at T1 and does not continue to T2 and T3, "2" and "3" respectively.

Any ideas? Same thing happens using the other two loop forms.

Edit: I am using a mac.

Edit: picture attached

[Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxTXB.png)

Comment: It worked for me. Can you show us all of the code including any declarations plz?

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply Tom, I have attached a screenshot above.

Comment: It worked for me, too. Maybe try `Cells(i, 1).Value = i`?

Comment: Yeah seems my computer just stops after one iteration seems like there is an underlying problem with my computer rather than excel thanks anyway guys

Comment: Is this the only macro in your whole workbook? Any on change events going about? What happens if you step through the code using f8?